# xcodebuild tests on a clone device

Tags: xcodebuild, xcrun

I'm trying to run a simulator, amend it's appearance, set the status bar, and finally run tests on it.

```
# $UUID is an existing simulator in the CoreSimulator/Devices folder

$ Boot up an existing simulator
xcrun simctl boot $UUID

# Amend appearance to dark
xcrun simctl ui booted appearance "dark"

# Set status bar
xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time "09:41" --cellularMode 'active' --operatorName 'Test'
```

This correctly boots up the right simulator with the correct amendments/status bar.

```
# Execute the test on the prepared simulator
xcodebuild -scheme $schemeName -project $projectName  -derivedDataPath '/tmp/TestDerivedData/' -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,id=$UUID" build test
```

Unfortunately, xcodebuild creates a clone of the simulator, and runs the test on the clone:

```
SimDevice: Clone 1 of iPhone 8 Plus (463C36F0-2E89-4E51-B59A-4F8EB20F124C, iOS 13.4)
```

The cloned simulator **does** have the set appearance of the original simulator, but not the set status bar.

Question: can I prevent xcodebuild to spin up a clone and have it test on the prepared simulator? If not, can I modify the appearance of the cloned simulator before the test is run?

Answer (score 1):

```
xcodebuild -disable-concurrent-destination-testing
```

This disables cloning.